# Run-time error '1004': Method 'FormulaR1C1' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: vba, excel, methods, range

I am trying to create a simple macro which basically is adding a new colum, naming it, pasting the formula and filling down. The error I get is as in the subject:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'FormulaR1C1' of object 'Range' failed

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(OR($G2=DATA!$L$3;G2=DATA!$L$4;$G2=DATA!$L$5;$G2=DATA!$L$6;$G2=DATA!$L$7;$G2=DATA!$L$8;$G2=DATA!$L$9;$G2=DATA!$L$10);DATA!$L$2; IF(OR($G2=DATA!$M$3;G2=DATA!$M$4;$G2=DATA!$M$5;$G2=DATA!$M$6;$G2=DATA!$M$7;$G2=DATA!$M$8;$G2=DATA!$M$9;$G2=DATA!$M$10);DATA!$M$2; IF(OR($G2=DATA!$N$3;G2=DATA!$N$4;$G2=DATA!$N$5;$G2=DATA!$N$6;$G2=DATA!$N$7;$G2=DATA!$N$8;$G2=DATA!$N$9;$G2=DATA!$N$10);DATA!$N$2; IF(OR($G2=DATA!$O$3;G2=DATA!$O$4;$G2=DATA!$O$5;$G2=DATA!$O$6;$G2=DATA!$O$7;$G2=DATA!$O$8;$G2=DATA!$O$9;$G2=DATA!$O$10);DATA!$O$2; IF(OR($G2=DATA!$P$3;G2=DATA!$P$4;$G2=DATA!$P$5;$G2=DATA!$P$6;$G2=DATA!$P$7;$G2=DATA!$P$8;$G2=DATA!$P$9;$G2=DATA!$P$10);DATA!$P$2; "OTHER")))))
```

And the macro:

```
Sub Macro16()
'
' Macro16 Macro
'

'
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CSS Team"
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(RC7=DATA!R3C12,RC[-2]=DATA!R4C12,RC7=DATA!R5C12,RC7=DATA!R6C12,RC7=DATA!R7C12,RC7=DATA!R8C12,RC7=DATA!R9C12,RC7=DATA!R10C12),DATA!R2C12, IF(OR(RC7=DATA!R3C13,RC[-2]=DATA!R4C13,RC7=DATA!R5C13,RC7=DATA!R6C13,RC7=DATA!R7C13,RC7=DATA!R8C13,RC7=DATA!R9C13,RC7=DATA!R10C13),DATA!R2C13, IF(OR(RC7=DATA!R3C14,RC[-2]=DATA!R4C14,RC7=DATA!R5C14,RC7=DATA!R6C14,RC7=DATA!R7C" & _
        "ATA!R8C14,RC7=DATA!R9C14,RC7=DATA!R10C14),DATA!R2C14, IF(OR(RC7=DATA!R3C15,RC[-2]=DATA!R4C15,RC7=DATA!R5C15,RC7=DATA!R6C15,RC7=DATA!R7C15,RC7=DATA!R8C15,RC7=DATA!R9C15,RC7=DATA!R10C15),DATA!R2C15, IF(OR(RC7=DATA!R3C16,RC[-2]=DATA!R4C16,RC7=DATA!R5C16,RC7=DATA!R6C16,RC7=DATA!R7C16,RC7=DATA!R8C16,RC7=DATA!R9C16,RC7=DATA!R10C16),DATA!R2C16, ""OTHER"")))))"
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I21445")
    Range("I2:I21445").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

At 663 characters, your formula may be too long to be stuffed into a cell as the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) or [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527(v=office.12).aspx) but of primary concern is the fact that VBA is very EN-US centric and your formula must be passed into the property with commas as list separators, not semi-coloons regardless of the fact that your computer's regional system specifies the semi-colon as the list separator character and that you use a semi-colon when typing a formula into the worksheet.

```
=IF(OR($G2=DATA!$L$3,G2=DATA!$L$4,$G2=DATA!$L$5,$G2=DATA!$L$6,$G2=DATA!$L$7,$G2=DATA!$L$8,$G2=DATA!$L$9,$G2=DATA!$L$10), DATA!$L$2, 
 IF(OR($G2=DATA!$M$3,G2=DATA!$M$4,$G2=DATA!$M$5,$G2=DATA!$M$6,$G2=DATA!$M$7,$G2=DATA!$M$8,$G2=DATA!$M$9,$G2=DATA!$M$10), DATA!$M$2, 
 IF(OR($G2=DATA!$N$3,G2=DATA!$N$4,$G2=DATA!$N$5,$G2=DATA!$N$6,$G2=DATA!$N$7,$G2=DATA!$N$8,$G2=DATA!$N$9,$G2=DATA!$N$10), DATA!$N$2, 
 IF(OR($G2=DATA!$O$3,G2=DATA!$O$4,$G2=DATA!$O$5,$G2=DATA!$O$6,$G2=DATA!$O$7,$G2=DATA!$O$8,$G2=DATA!$O$9,$G2=DATA!$O$10), DATA!$O$2, 
 IF(OR($G2=DATA!$P$3,G2=DATA!$P$4,$G2=DATA!$P$5,$G2=DATA!$P$6,$G2=DATA!$P$7,$G2=DATA!$P$8,$G2=DATA!$P$9,$G2=DATA!$P$10), DATA!$P$2,
   "OTHER")))))
```

If you absolutely need to use semi-colons, you can apply the remi-colon separated formula with the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx).

**-Addendum:**

I've cut your formula down to 98 characters in **xlA1** style.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!L$2:P$2, 1, AGGREGATE(15, 6, COLUMN($A:$E)/(Data!$L$3:$P$10=G2), 1)), "OTHER")
```

Your original formula is in F2 filled down to F8. The proposed formula above is in E2 filled down to E8.

[image: semi_colon_formula]

Comment: `FormulaR1C1` can hold a formula much longer than that - 8192 characters I think

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll try to check that. I was working under the impression that the limit when using VBA was much less but I'll check.

Comment: [This Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff700514(v=office.14).aspx) claims 8000 for Excel 2010 (up from 1000 in Excel 2003). And [this page](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) claims 8192